# Bigcommerce getTransaction call not returning expected result

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using a Bigcommerce sandbox account, which is not live yet. Test orders are allowed from backend. Two orders can be seen from admin: order_id 100 and 101. But when I am using Postman to get either one, response is:

```
{
  "status": 500,
  "code": 10000,
  "title": "Transactions not found for order_id 101. [Internal Code 204]",
  "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api#api-status-codes"
}
```

My Get call is:

```
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/<mystorehash>/v3/orders/101/transactions
```

I am using Postman with headers:

```
X-Auth-Client:<my API client id>
X-Auth-Token: <my Auth token>
```

I have got these values when I created the API....also there in header:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-type:application/json
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using a payment gateway in test mode or the "test gateway"?

Comment: Test gateway, I am using the test credit cards....The V2 orders API and products API are working perfectly, but V3 fails.

Comment: I believe this doesn't work for the test gateway. You can try test mode for another gateway.